# Aviation icon/favicon the same as Astronomy

Tags: discussion

The Aviation favicon is the same as the one for Astronomy.  Will this be changed?

[image: favicon for Astronomy and Aviation]

Comment: The mini icon on mobile is different, but the favicon is the same.

Comment: Also, this is only on Meta, the main site is not affected.

Comment: Ah yes, the flair icon has "Av".  Let me change the question to be specific to the favicon.

Comment: Some of our members on [space.se] had a similar problem when they changed the icon from SE to SX, but that turned out to be local browser caching problems. More on that problem is [described here](http://meta.space.stackexchange.com/q/392/49), but in a nutshell, I'd try a "hard refresh" on both main site and meta, which can be done on most browsers by pressing CTRL+F5 keys (holding down CTRL and then pressing F5 key). Some browsers are a bit stubborn and require this two times in a row, but wait between these refreshes so the page reloads completely. Hope this helps... ;)

Comment: How can we go about getting this implemented?

Comment: @TildalWave In my case refreshing did not work at all. I just had to wait for it to clear up.

Comment: By the way, I am also experiencing the same thing with Aviation's logo.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I think 'A' or 'Av' is pretty boring. Can't it be changed to something like this?

[image: a nicer favicon for aviation.stackexchane]

If those in control of the appearance of this site at Stack Exchange would like to have the scalable vector graphics that form the basis of this piece of art, just let me know :-)

*Edit:*

Thanks for all the upvotes! I've put in a [feature request](https://aviation.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/178/new-icon-for-aviation) to make this the new icon.

Comment: Not while in beta. [se] sites need to graduate first, then they get their own custom design, part of which is the icon. And even when we graduate, it might take a while to get the design with [so many sites](https://stackexchange.com/sites?view=grid) on a back order for the [se] design team. E.g. [money.se] still doesn't have it, even though they're graduated and out of beta for a while now, and [the design templates look great](http://meta.money.stackexchange.com/q/801). Well, they do to me ;)

Comment: Actually, I take my words back, some SE sites in beta do have slightly customized icons. They're still _white on sky blue background_, but they have a motif instead of letters, like for example [poker.se] and [chess.se]. OK, let's then "upboat" this proposal and see if we're heard :)

Comment: @TildalWave I've updated my answer to reflect what the icon would look like.

Comment: Not only do I think this is a great idea for the beta, I think it would be a fine permanent icon for the site. U+2708 (✈) could be used for a quick-and-dirty version too.