# New icon for Aviation

Tags: feature-request, status-completed

During the private beta it was noted that the [icon for Aviation was the same as for Astronomy](https://aviation.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75/aviation-icon-favicon-the-same-as-astronomy). My suggestion to change it to something less boring that just 'A' or 'Av' earned a *Nice Answer* badge (thank you all!) and so I am putting it forward as a feature request.

[image]

If it is of any help, I'll make the scalable vector graphics available to the design team.

Comment: I'll run it by our designer on Monday and see if there's interest in changing it while still in beta.

Comment: @BretCopeland awesome, thanks!

Comment: It still appears to be "A" in the menu: http://cdn.sstatic.net/img/favicons-sprite16.png?v=completeAndUtterCacheBustingGibberish

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Our icon - it changes!

[image: Main Icon]
[image: Meta Icon]

Comment: Despite the change a number of days ago, the favicon is no different for me, even after a Ctrl+F5 (forced refresh) on [favicons-sprite16.png](http://cdn.sstatic.net/img/favicons-sprite16.png), [favicon.ico](http://cdn.sstatic.net/aviation/img/favicon.ico) and [favicon.ico](http://cdn.sstatic.net/aviationmeta/img/favicon.ico): [Example Image](http://i.stack.imgur.com/kmib0.png)

Comment: The favicon was ***very*** persistent for me (at least in Safari) - I had to delete the entire favicon database to get it to refresh. I imagine other browsers are as stubborn about it and don't keep it in the "normal" cache location. http://aviation.stackexchange.com/favicon.ico is (or at least redirects to) the correct icon though :)

Comment: I can't get the sprites working, but the favicon appears to be working for me.

Comment: Just to update on this, using a browser (sic, Firefox) that has never accessed the site before, I'm *still* seeing the old icon: http://i.stack.imgur.com/9aQEn.png Is it possible there's a problem with your CDN?